# nodejs USR2 signal kills process using heapdump

Tags: node.js, node-heapdump

Using [heapdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heapdump), I'm trying to take some heap snapshots of node

as per https://blog.risingstack.com/finding-a-memory-leak-in-node-js/

Sending USR2 to a node process that has required heapdump should trigger heapdump to save a heap snapshot to the working directory.

On my local server (running on a mac) this works great.  On an AWS ubuntu server, USR2 kills the process.  I've also tried SIGUSR2.

Does anyone know why "sudo kill -USR2 " would be killing the process instead of triggering a heap snapshot?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I did

Answer (score 4):

This could happen because of two reasons:

- In some distros the kill code is `USR2` and in others it's `SIGUSR2`. You need to run `kill -l` to check which one your distro supports.
- `require('heapdump')` is not executed in the current worker. So if you are use node `cluster` module then you need to require heapdump in the current worker i.e.

if (worker.isMaster) {
   /* master stuff */
} else {
    require('heapdump')
}